# search engine like google search

Tags: javascript, keypress, onkeyup

am trying to do search engine same like **google** search using `html ajax` and `jsp`

1.When i hit a character in my text box it calls `ajax` for every hit

2.`ajax` redirects it to `jsp` where i have a simple query which fetches employee names from employee table.and stores it in result set.

3.through this result set am displaying `emp` names in `combo box, onchange` in combo box it display in my text box .
My problem is  am not able to take event.`keycode` value from combo box because keycode only works in `keyup` and `keydown` and this is not available in combo box option.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by combobox you mean a `<select>` with `multiple` set. You will not be able to do this as there are no key-based events associated with those elements.

What you will want to do is use a standard text `<input>` field and display a div directly under it with the search results. This is how auto-complete is almost always done. You can see a great example in the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) page.

You can always implement this yourself, but I would highly recommend off-loading this Javascript code to jQuery. It's already been done for you.

Comment: i dnt know abt jquery am new bee in this can you tell me how to achieve this . in your link there is no reference code, is ther way to find code example thanks for u r response

Comment: If you click the "view source" link it will display the code used in the example.

Comment: thanks just know i come to know that jquery is a plugin its great to achieve my goal, do you have any simple example on this

Answer (score 1):

JQuery plugin [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) handles such things pretty well from client side.